# Problem when using Servo.h and WIre.h libraries

Tags: arduino-uno, servo, wire-library

I have a project that consists of an Arduino, a NodeMCU and 2 servos. The NodeMCU is configured as master and the Arduino as slave. I have bidirectional flow of data between them.

In order to receive data from Arduino I use the `requestFrom()` function from the Wire.h library and I call this function in the NodeMCU loop every 100ms.

The problem is that the servos (which are connected to the Arduino to pins 10 and 11) twitch every approximatively 10s. If I change the interval at which the NodeMCU asks for data from Arduino to 200ms, the twitch interval for the servos changes to 20s.

Is there a buffer that gets full or what is happening? I think that the `Wire.onRequest()` handler from Arduino interferes with the PWM of the servos. Is there a workaround? Do you have any idea how to stop the servos from twitching? Perhaps make the libraries use different timers? Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
#include "Arduino.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Keypad.h>
#include <Servo.h>


Servo servo_1;//up-down servo
Servo servo_2;//left-right servo

byte deg_1=0;
byte deg_2=0;
 
byte manual_move_mode = 0;

byte data_count = 0, master_count = 0;  

const byte ROWS = 4;
const byte COLS = 4;

char hexaKeys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

byte rowPins[ROWS] = {9, 8, 7, 6};
byte colPins[COLS] = {5, 4, 3, 2};

Keypad customKeypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(hexaKeys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS);

void setup() {
 Wire.begin(8);                /* join i2c bus with address 8 */
 Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); /* register receive event */
 Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
 Serial.begin(115200);           /* start serial for debug */
 Serial.println("Program Started");
 pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
 
 servo_1.attach(10);
 servo_1.write(0);
 servo_2.attach(11);
 servo_2.write(0);
}

void loop() {
  
 manual_move_servo();
 //send_keys();
 
}


// function that executes when data is received from master
void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
  String data="";
 while (0 <Wire.available()) {
    char c = Wire.read();      /* receive byte as a character */
    data += c;
    
  }
    Serial.println(data);   /* print the request data */

    if (data=="PIN_13_HIGH"){
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
   } else if (data == "PIN_13_LOW"){
    digitalWrite(13,LOW);
   }

    if (data=="MANUAL_TRUE"){
    manual_move_mode = 1;
   } else if (data == "MANUAL_FALSE"){
    manual_move_mode = 0;
   }
}

void requestEvent()
{
  char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();
  if (customKey){
    Serial.print("Transmission to NodeMCU begins...");
    Serial.println(customKey);
    Wire.write(customKey);  // sends hello string 
  }
}

void manual_move_servo(){
  if (manual_move_mode == 1){
      char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();
  if (customKey=='2'){//move up
    //digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    deg_1+=5;
    servo_1.write(deg_1);
  } else if(customKey=='8'){//move down
    //digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    deg_1-=5;
    servo_1.write(deg_1);
  } else if(customKey=='4'){//move left
    //digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    deg_2+=5;
    servo_2.write(deg_2);
  } else if(customKey=='6'){//move right
    //digitalWrite(13,LOW);
    deg_2-=5;
    servo_2.write(deg_2);
  } else if(customKey=='*'){
    manual_move_mode = 0;//este nevoie sa trimitem inf asta spre nodemcu????? nu cred pentru ca nu comandam altceva in fctie de var asta cu nodemcu poate doar daca adaugam un led indicator pe interfata web
  }
  }
//ne asiguram ca nu trecem de intervalele impuse
  if (deg_1<=5){
    deg_1=5;//daca pun 0 se duce automat la 180(probabil se intercaleaza intervale)
  }

  if (deg_1>=180){
    deg_1=180;
  }

    if (deg_2<=5){
    deg_2=5;//daca pun 0 se duce automat la 180(probabil se intercaleaza intervale)
  }

  if (deg_2>=180){
    deg_2=180;
  }
}

/*void send_keys(){

    char customKey = customKeypad.getKey();
  
  if (customKey){
    Serial.println(customKey);
    Serial.print("Transmission to NodeMCU begins...");
    Wire.beginTransmission(47); // begin with device address 8 
    Wire.write(customKey);  // sends hello string 
    Wire.endTransmission();// stop transmitting 
  }
}*/
```

Comment: Please show us your code. The servo library and the Wire library both make use of Interrupt Service Routines. The `onRequest()` callback function is called from an ISR. If it takes too long to execute the ISR of the servo motors might have to wait, thus the motors are twitching. At least that would be my theory.

Comment: You could drive the servos directly from two PWM pins, instead of using the Servo library which uses an ISR. I'd suggest using the pins 9 and 10, as those use timer1. See https://forum.arduino.cc/t/servo-motor-controlled-by-timer-1-to-prevent-jitter/483767

Comment: @chrisl I added the code for the Arduino

Comment: Please try to do the very minimum of work inside the `onRequest()` and `onReceive()` callback functions. These are called from an ISR. For the `onRequest()` read the keypad in the main code and just prepare a variable (declared as `volatile`), which you then just do `Wire.write()` with in the `onRequest()` callback function. Reading the keypad takes some time. Also be cautious with printing too much to Serial inside an ISR. If it fills the buffer it can block your entire code and the data will only be send after the ISR is left.

Comment: So if I remove code from the onRequest() and onReceive() the servos should stop twitching?

Comment: I'll try to use hardware PWM instead of timer interrupts for the servos but I do not really know how (i'm gonna read about this). I have used the ServoTimer2 library but that does not work so is the hardware PWM going to work( I believe it is a different concept?; does it also use timers?)

Comment: I managed to stop the servos from twitching by removing the keypad reading from the onRequest() function. Thanks a lot!